How complex is the God of Classical Theism?
From Wikipedia:

Classical theism is a theological and philosophical form of theism that conceives of God as the ultimate, transcendent reality, characterized by attributes such as omnipotence, omniscience, and perfect goodness. Rooted in the ancient Greek philosophy of Plato and Aristotle, classical theism presents God as a being who is immutable, impassible, and entirely self-sufficient. This understanding of God emphasizes divine simplicity, where God's essence and existence are identical, making Him fundamentally distinct from all created beings.
Throughout history, classical theism has significantly shaped the doctrines of major religious traditions, particularly within Christianity, Judaism, and Islam. The early Church Fathers, like Augustine, incorporated classical theistic ideas into Christian theology, establishing a framework that was later refined by medieval thinkers such as Thomas Aquinas. In Jewish thought, philosophers like Maimonides emphasized the unity and transcendence of God, aligning closely with classical theistic principles. Similarly, Islamic philosophers such as Avicenna and Al-Ghazali adopted classical theistic concepts to articulate a vision of God as utterly singular and beyond human comprehension.
Despite its profound influence, classical theism has been subject to significant critique, particularly in the modern era. Philosophers and theologians have challenged the coherence of attributes like divine simplicity and immutability, questioning how an unchanging God can interact with a dynamic world or respond to human prayer.

Notice that the article references the concept of divine simplicity, which Wikipedia defines as follows:

In classical theistic and monotheistic theology, the doctrine of divine simplicity says that God is simple (without parts). God exists as one unified entity, with no distinct attributes; God's existence is identical to God's essence.

So, a trivial answer to my question might be "God is simple," but does that truly make sense? How can something simple be omniscient, possessing knowledge of potentially infinitely many things? If the God of classical theism has a mind, it seems to me that the contents of this mind must be infinitely complex when considering every single fact it knows.
How complex, then, is the God of classical theism?

You are comparing the theological "simple" with the scientific "complex". An unicellular organism is simple (i.e. without parts) and thus must be omniscient?

Casually waving your hand (or other appendage, or no appendage) and having the universe adjust certainly seems simple to me.  I don't see why you think complexity is necessary. This is part of why I can't believe in a god small enough to matter.

Yes, even a 10 year old instinctively knows that a Being who can literally do anything is complex. He can listen to your prayers, monitor the entire universe at every second, etc. Any time we’ve actually implemented something that can do many functions (I.e. a computer), it has without exception been complex. Most people who in response to this claim that the notion that “complex” is subjective must be prepared to admit that every concept in philosophy is subjective, so that’s not a good retort.

The way I view "simple" as defined here, is simply that God is Indivisible, fundamental. You cannot partition God into distinct parts. Equivalently, God is not the Sum of non-God Attributes. There is an analogy to infinity, you cannot reach infinity by adding something finitely many times.  It really has nothing to do with the simple/complex dichotomy of say- multicellular vs Single Cellular Organisms

@syed: a 10-year-old's instincts are not philosophy.

@keshlam it’s rhetorical

Things I don't understand seem simple. The more I learn about them the more complex they seem.

It might be better to replace "complex" with "complicated". An electron is simple but complicated - it takes an entire theory (Quantum Electrodynamics) to grasp the complicated behavior of this ontologically simple (i.e., non-composite) object.
God may be un-composed to the highest degree, as if God is this necessary, singleton, fundamental particle. There is only one G-particle, and it is the same one in all possible worlds for all time.
What they really mean by "simple" is that, unlike normal objects, God is not an instance of his properties. A red ball is an instance of the property "redness" and "roundness", but so is a stoplight. Not so with God. No other object, even in principle, can instantiate "omniscience" or "omnipotence" or "pure existence/potential" - so when you find it, you necessarily have found God. Therefore, God is his essence since God is a singular entity.
However, it's hard for me to see how God is not complicated in the sense that God does a lot of things, and theologians often say God is "incomprehensible" -- not something one would say about something that is "uncomplicated". The sheer volume of theological works written about God show how complicated God is. There's a lot to unpack when we are talking about God.
Therefore, God is a lot like a fundamental particle: simple but complicated.
It didn't have to be this way: If we say God is identical to the property of existence itself, then God is pretty uncomplicated: God = Existence. There is anything at all because of this thing called "God" that allows for particulars to exist. But we don't do this; instead, we attribute a lot of properties to God ("analogically" per Aquinas) rendering God not just a shorthand for a collection of properties, but as somehow an agent that does things and has a relationship with us. That is pretty complicated to do across all space and time.

Appendix on metaphysical systems underlying the debate
The SEP has a nice summary of the doctrine of divine simplicity (DDS):

According to the classical theism of Augustine, Anselm, Aquinas and their adherents, God is radically unlike creatures and cannot be adequately understood in ways appropriate to them. God is simple in that God transcends every form of complexity and composition familiar to the discursive intellect. One consequence is that the simple God lacks parts. This lack is not a deficiency but a positive feature. God is ontologically superior to every partite entity, and his partlessness is an index thereof. Broadly construed, ‘part’ covers not only spatial and temporal parts (if any) but also metaphysical ‘parts’ or ontological constituents. To say that God lacks metaphysical parts is to say inter alia that God is free of matter-form composition, potency-act composition, and existence-essence composition. There is also no real distinction between God as subject of his attributes and his attributes. God is thus in some sense identical to each of his attributes, which implies that each attribute is identical to every other one. God is omniscient, then, not in virtue of instantiating or exemplifying omniscience — which would imply a real distinction between God and the property of omniscience — but by being omniscience

I would also note that there is a long history of philosophical challenges to its very coherence (e.g. Plantinga - a famous Christian theist). Most of the SEP article is about this but I'll highlight the key insight into what makes "God is simple" so hard to comprehend.

DDS cannot be made sense of within a nonconstituent ontology. It can be made sense of, assuming it can be made sense of, only within a constituent ontology, the style of ontology presupposed by its main defender, Aquinas. A nonconstituent ontologist like Plantinga may be represented as arguing by Modus Ponens: If God exemplifies his nature, then he is distinct from it; God exemplifies his nature; ergo, God is distinct from his nature, and DDS is false. But the constituent ontologist is justified in switching to Modus Tollens: If God exemplifies his nature, then he is distinct from it; God is not distinct from his nature; ergo, God does not exemplify his nature but has his nature by being identical with it.

The jury is still out on whether DDS is actually coherent. I find it incoherent, but many would appeal to God's singular nature and our lack of familiarity with anything like God (apart from God). Basically, "If you cannot understand my theory, it is a problem with you, not my theory."

I think you have invested much labour into your exegesis of these technical terms from theology, notably concerning DDS. Eventually you comment “I find it incoherent”, and your final sentence is a nice ironical wordplay. Do you think it is possible at all to translate this kind of theologians’ speech into a consistent and convincing theory?

@JoWehler unfortunately I think if that could be done it would have been by any number of brilliant theologians over the last 800 years. The fact that even a great like Plantinga challenges the coherence of DDS is very telling - he’s about as sympathetic as you’re gonna get!

@JoWehler more broadly — after reading Summa and more modern Thomists — it all ends up feeling like sterile wordplay that has excessive precision without a point - you aren’t going to convince someone to throw out all observational evidence to the contrary and believe in a god on the basis of a clever use of definitions and/or abstruse terminology.

@JoWehler honestly I wonder if they really want to be understood or simply intimidate people with their apparent erudition.

@annika: best explanation of why these gymnastics were considered essential that I've seen yet is in Ada Palmer's blog  Ex Urbe, specifically the ongoing "history of skepticism" series. I'd suggest starting at the beginning of that thread so you have the background later posts refer to, but you could skip to part 3, where she gets into why the church, specifically, spent so much effort on trying to prove watch they already believed: https://www.exurbe.com/sketches-of-a-history-of-skepticism-part-3-cicero-through-scholasticism/

It wasn't intended to convince the unbelievers, but to make sure that the believers weren't teaching falsehoods that could lead to their students being damned. Unfortunately for them, in mutually critiquing those efforts they laid the grounds for questioning the assumptions as well as the derived details.

@keshlam — very interesting! Will take a look :)

(what, not watch. I hate auto defect..)

Another complication: those later classical theologians were Trinitarians. Of course, they weren’t allowed to question orthodoxy.

god is nothing like a fundamental particle. One can do anything and everything. The other is a very basic constituent of processes in the universe. There is no way in which one can say god is simple

"you aren’t going to convince someone to throw out all observational evidence to the contrary..." This statement seems to propagate the erroneous presumption that discovery of an underlying physical process rebuts any higher level root cause. Like measuring the wavelength of reflected light and determining the material composition of the pigment responsible for the effect sufficiently explains the color of the eyes in Leonardo's Mona Lisa.  Unless you know of direct observational evidence against God?

@MichaelHall Can you clarify how my comment relates to to rebutting higher level causes? I think I was merely getting at that people done really come to believe based on these complex logic games -- I actually think the real driver is closer to what you say above in terms of higher-order considerations (color vs beauty, reproduction vs love)

It "seems to", but perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by "all observational evidence to the contrary" Which observations? What evidence? Contrary to what?

I understand your post as asking “How complex is the God-concept of classical theism?”
In philosophy one can only assess the concept of God.
My answer: The God-concept is not only complex, it is overloaded with a heavy bunch of complex attributes. Most of them are not well-defined, some are mutually inconsistent, and all are raised to superlative form. Your list illustrates the situation.

As with the other answers, while this makes sense from a contemporary perspective, I don't see it as doing justice to the original conception of theological simplicity and its neoplatonist origins.

@ChrisSunami I do not see how you define “simple” – also not in your elaborated answer. - And similarly I do not understand the wikipedia statement that God is simple because he has no parts.

Theological simplicity has its roots in Neoplatonism. The idea is that the phenomenal world is an illusion, and that True Reality exists in a more abstract, simpler, perfect realm. We can imagine a kind of metaphysical solar system, where God (or "The One") exists at the center, like the sun, and all other things are in orbit at various distances (things "close" are perfect, eternal, abstract and simple, things "at a distance" are complex, temporary, corporeal and corrupt). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neoplatonism
When we describe or contemplate things in the ordinary world, we are doing so in a language and a context that isn't suited to the eternal realm. So all we can do is to describe those things using metaphors and analogies. Which, under the Neoplatonist read of Plato, is what Plato is doing in all his dialogs--using elaborate metaphors to create portraits of God. So the short answer would be that the complexity when we talk about God is an artifact of our inability to understand or discuss God as God actually is.
It's worth noting, however, that the original Neoplatonist idea of God, sometimes called "God of the Philosophers" or "The Unity of All Perfections" (perfectly good, perfectly wise, perfectly beautiful, perfectly eternal, etc.) is abstract and not personified. The Neoplatonist influence on Islamic and Christian theology identified "The One" with God as understood in those religions, and it's not always a comfortable fit. It's easier to justify theological simplicity as applying to "The One" than to God as personified in the religious traditions.

He's however complex your arbitrary complexity function returns when input your arbitrary definition of God.
If you follow the classical theists and define something like "God is beyond human comprehension and can only be described by imperfect analogy and understood by direct revelation, being fundamentally unlike all other objects" and input that into a complexity function that only takes well defined inputs (like a simulatable system of mathematically represented state variables), you're going to get a category error.
If you arbitrarily select your complexity function to take that input and output the divine simplicity conclusion, or whatever else you wanted, you get what you designed it to give you.
If you take a list of the imperfect analogies and plug them into a complexity function designed to output the complexity of a machine with a well defined list of attributes, you'll probably get a large number, but you're no longer evaluating the complexity of God as defined above. As Jo Wehler noted, we can assess the complexity of theism, but that's not the same as assessing the complexity of God.
My personal preference is that any useful assessment of complexity is the sort that can't take a theistic God as an input, so asking the complexity of God is a category error: God in, garbage out. But I'm not the boss of arbitrary complexity functions, so if you want one that inputs God and outputs 39.772 standard imperial Occams, go for it.

The complexity of god is as arbitrary as the complexity of a human by your logic, yet no one argues that humans are simple. Just because He is ill defined sometimes doesn’t change the fact that a lot of interpretations of God involve Him being All Powerful/All Knowing/etc. A Being who can quite literally do anything and knows everything is anything but simple, and this shouldn’t be a matter of debate. The “hard to understand” nature of God is just a cop out by theists to prevent people from reaching this obvious conclusion

Even if God was posited to be or was the most simple being possible (and there’s many reasons as to why noone should think this), positing god necessarily adds more to your ontology. It is not as if the complexity of the universe magically goes away if you posit god. So you’re comparing god + universe with just the universe.
Thus, theism is necessarily more complex than atheism, unless one can show that theism simplifies all the observations we have but there is nothing within the concept of god that predicts everything that we see in the world. We have no further explanation, for example, as to why someone’s grandmother died today by positing god than without god.

Yes, He is complex. He can listen to your prayers, monitor the entire universe at every second, etc. Any time we’ve actually implemented something that can do many functions (I.e. a computer), it has without exception been complex. Most people who in response to this claim that the notion of “complex” is subjective must be prepared to admit that every concept in philosophy is subjective, so that’s not a good retort.
This can be made clearer by comparing God to items that we already agree is complex. For example, we all agree that a supercomputer is extremely complex. But a supercomputer is only one of the many things that God can create. The creator of X who can also create Y, Z, and A must be more complex than X.
The idea of divine simplicity results from a cognitive error. We may be able to imagine complexity without components, but this doesn’t mean that this is actually possible, or even sensible.
As Richard Carrier puts it here,

This inconsistency, between how simple we think a phenomenon is, and how complex it actually is, is a routine error in human cognition. We’ve run into this repeatedly in AI development: try programming a car to roll up a hill (staying on the road; pushing against gravity). It’s far more complex a program than you probably assumed. I mean, it seems so simple. Car, direction, roll. Just three words. Surely the simplest thing ever! Nope. It’s actually very complicated. Even in a simulation, like a computer game, where you totally control all the laws of physics, and can literally just make a car roll uphill by simply saying that it does, the code—even the most efficient code logically possible—is really incredibly complicated. It’s not just three words. Even if you wrote an operating system that could do it with three words, that would just conceal the complexity in the operating system. Try coding “car, roll uphill” with just the words “car, roll uphill,” without any underlying operating system (much less physical processors and memory chips). Nothing will happen. Because it can’t.


"The creator of X who can also create Y, Z, and A must be more complex than X." but theory of evolution would say that creator can be indeed simpler.

Monitoring the entire universe is incompatible with quantum mechanics.

@Corbin So? That just adds less credence to the god hypothesis
